# format a volume as xfs

Tags: ext3, xfs, format

I have a partition that is formatted as ext3
I dd unmount it. Formatted as xfs (for quicker format) and I got an error.
When I formatted it as ext3 again, it worked. What is the command to format an ext3 as xfs ?
This is an Amazon EBS volume that I need to empty.

```
# umount /data

 # time mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdf1
meta-data=/dev/sdf1              isize=256    agcount=32, agsize=8388565 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=268434080, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks, unwritten=1
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=32768, version=1
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=0
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0

real    0m11.238s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

# mount /data
mount: special device /dev/sdm does not exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mkfs.xfs` worked fine; you got an error on mount because you're trying to mount the wrong thing.  Try `mount /dev/sdf1 /data` and things will probably work out significantly better.  Or you could edit your `/etc/fstab` to reflect the correct device-to-mountpoint mapping, and then use `mount /data` as you've been doing.